# How to Create a Box Shadow?

Tags: css, shadow

I'm trying to create a shadow under the [lower nav bar on this site](http://glamourunderground.com). But the CSS below doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Tara

```
#catmenucontainer {
    height:25px;
    background:#333333;
    display:block;
    padding:0px 0 0px 0px;
    font: 18px helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

Comment: I was looking through your markup and i would advise you to simplify it. You have div elements inside ul elements and that is invalid html. The only element that can exist inside a ul element is a li (list item) element.

Comment: @Pedro - Thanks, but as far as I can tell, this is the only HTML I have control over '<div id="foxmenucontainer">
 <div id="catmenu">
   <ul>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-2' ) ); ?>
   </ul>
 </div>  
</div>
<div id="catmenucontainer">
 <div id="catmenu">
   <ul>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1' ) ); ?>
   </ul>
 </div>  
</div>' since I'm using wordpress's menus. I suppose I could pull it out and start from scratch though if it's really a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of your code without the offending elements:
[Menu with css3 shadow](http://jsfiddle.net/pedrocorreia/HKbN8/)

Comment: so you're saying that the problem is with the misplaced divs in the menus?

Comment: Check seler's answer. It solves your display problem. I would anyway advise you to run your site through a html validator and remove all hmtl errors, if you can. It will save you a lot of grief.

Answer (score 1):

shadow it's working. it's just that `div#casing` is covering it.

```
#catmenucontainer {
    position: relative;
    z-index:2
}
#casing {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried this, it's now showing the shadow @norsrac mentioned below, but the catmenu has somehow increased in hight at the same time.

Comment: @Tara you must have changed something else. go back to time where you posted your question and add my css code. it will show your gray shadow. 

now it's `#catmenu { height: 40px }` what's affecting height of menu.

Comment: But my CSS is `#catmenucontainer{
 position: relative;
     z-index:2
 height:25px;}` right now. UPDATE: Sorry! You were right. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the shadow still isn't working (I replaced the original in the CSS) it just doesn't show.

Comment: @Tara if it's about this version online: http://www.glamourunderground.com/ i think it's because YOU HAVENT SPECIFIED ANY SHADOW THERE (and no z-index too). you should really check your code with w3c validators (xhtml and css3).

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is fine and I can confirm it works.  Try this and tinker with it until you get it where you want it:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
```

Comment: Thank you for the code... Unfortunately, for some reason this seems to be making a shadow on top of the lower nav bar rather than below it..?